# PHP local variable suggestion

Tags: php, variables, aptana

I've installed Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805 and everything works fine on my Windows 7 machine. Nevertheless I have a little question concerning code competition:
Is it right, that Aptana can't suggest in it's proposal list the use of local variables?

[A little piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reEpW.jpg)

I am sorry if this question was asked before, but I didn't find the right answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana will list local variables but you might need to type the first couple of characters first.